# How to fix *ngIf statements in menu?

Tags: angular

I'm setting up my first angular application, and I'm trying to showing menu options according the currently user

This is part of my menu code:

```
<a *ngIf="areYouHeadMaster() == 'true'" class="navbar-item" routerLink="/announcement">
      announcement
      </a>
```

areYouHeadMaster method:

```
  areYouHeadMaster(){
    console.log(this.transferData.getData());
      return this.transferData.getData();
  }
```

TransferData is service with only one variable and set, get method. In console log I get value True, but link is not added to menu.

Comment: Can you show us what `getData` looks like?

Comment: Please share your `TransferData` code. Also, as a good practice avoid function calls for `*ng` bindings. Rather call the `getData()` in `ngOnInit` lifecycle method and maintain a local reference in your component class. In case the value in the service can change dynamically, use RxJS to broadcast from the service and subscriptions in the component.

Comment: I don't believe (though can easily be wrong) that the *ngIf works properly with getter/setter properties. As it doesn't sound like this value is going to change, just use a normal variable that is set in the ngOnInit

Comment: *ngIf="areYouHeadMaster() == 'true'" - String comparison in angular are case sensitive. Did you try changing this to *ngIf="areYouHeadMaster() == 'True'". Because you mentioned "In console log I get value True"

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't treat `true` as a string (quoted). It's a logical value, so `== true` will do
2. You can use implied logic: `*ngIf="areYouHeadMaster()"` and skip the explicit check for true/false
3. If `this.transferData.getData();` is an async call, run it in `ngOnInit` and assign the result to a scoped variable. Use the variable in the template, instead of the function call `*ngIf="isHeadmaster"`.

Comment: I was looking for a mistake for an hour and did not notice quotes... thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If `getData()` returns a boolean value, your ngIf expression is wrong, since `true == 'true'` resolves to `false`. Try `true` without single quotes:

```
<a *ngIf="areYouHeadMaster() == true" class="navbar-item" routerLink="/announcement">
      announcement
      </a>
```

or even shorter, omit the comparison:

```
<a *ngIf="areYouHeadMaster()" class="navbar-item" routerLink="/announcement">
      announcement
      </a>
```

Comment: I was looking for a mistake for an hour and did not notice quotes... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this method to as shown below:

```
areYouHeadMaster(){
  console.log(this.transferData.getData());
  return this.transferData.getData().toLowerCase();
}
```

String comparisons in angular are case sensitive. Since you have mentioned, "In console log I get value True", which is different from "true".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing a boolean value to a string try this

```
<a *ngIf="areYouHeadMaster() == true" class="navbar-item" routerLink="/announcement">
  announcement
</a>
```